# Save Custom Post Type Title in Gravity Form Hidden Field

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, custom-post-type, gravityforms

I am trying to save the custom post type title with gravity form.Currently each post on careers page have form in it so when a user submit the form it should save the custom post type title as well.Each post is showing as accordion and each accordion have gravity form.I would like to know how do i save that current accordion post tile with form submission.Please check the screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a Hidden field to your form.
2. Set the Default Value of your Hidden field to `{embed_post:post_title}`.

Done! When the form is rendered, the post title of whatever post the form is being displayed on will be populated into your Hidden field and saved to the entry when the form is submitted.

Comment: Hi, the thing is this is not a single post page so i would like to know will it work on the main of custom post type where all the posts are showing ?